# response sendRedirect() processing

Tags: java, jsp, httpresponse

```
    if(condition true){
    request.sendRedirect("//Some URL");}

    // Some other code
```

Now my question is when we redirect, the some other code will execute or not ? If execute when, before sendRedirect or after sendRedirect ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `sendRedirect` method does not halt the execution of your method.

You should either branch your code in such a way that the call to `sendRedirect` is the last statement in your method, or explicitly call `return;` after calling `sendRedirect`.

See also http://www.coderanch.com/t/556146/Servlets/java/response-SendRedirect-session

Answer (score 2):

It would be very confusing to do some stuff after redirect, so it should be the last statement of the flow. Commit, close your stuffs before redirect to help understanding your code.